# Issue with auto layout - vertical spacing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder

In Xcode 8 with Swift 3 I'm using custom cell with auto layout. Information into cell inserted from JSON, so my code looks like:

```
    //the method returning each cell of the list
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Feedcell", for: indexPath) as! FruitTableViewCell

    //getting the hero for the specified position
    let hero: List_Feed
    hero = heroes[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelAnswer.text = hero.answer
    cell.labelQuestion.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell.labelQuestion.text = hero.question
    cell.labelQuestion.sizeToFit()
    cell.labelAnswer.sizeToFit()

    return cell
    }
```

[image]

[image]

**Problem is** that I'm getting equal labelQuestion heigh for each cell, but text size and line size are different. How to solve this? :c

[image]

Comment: Your label height increased due to height of cell . try to give background color to find which label height is increased

Comment: if your today label is one lined label then give height constraint to it

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya sorry, but it didn't worked, I've attached a photo to question

Comment: Please check answer

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I've commented it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Cell is reusing the Label You have to empty label before use for next cell

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Feedcell", for: indexPath) as! FruitTableViewCell

    //EMPTY LABELS
    cell.labelAnswer.text = ""
    cell.labelQuestion.text = ""

     self.layoutIfNeeded()

    //getting the hero for the specified position
    let hero: List_Feed
    hero = heroes[indexPath.row]

    cell.labelAnswer.text = hero.answer
    cell.labelQuestion.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    cell.labelQuestion.text = hero.question
    cell.labelQuestion.sizeToFit()
    cell.labelAnswer.sizeToFit()

    return cell
}
```

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: Thank you very much, dear friend, but it's still not working :/

Comment: I found where is problem. Because of text is in Cyrillic, one letter takes space for 3-4 letters, because it's a code, not a letter actually. And how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

1- set vertical content hugging priority off today label to 1000

2- hook the bottom of the label [ that is under today label ] to the top of the imageView Below it

3- hook bottom of the most-down label to bottom of contentView

Edit :

Add this 2 lines before return cell in **cellForRowAt**

```
  cell.layoutSubviews()

  cell.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, friend. I've did 1-, but I don't understand what is 2-. And 3- is already hooked to the bottom. Please check the question for added photo.

Comment: 2 and 3 will be as you did if the bottom most label is one line

Comment: No, issue is that Question label is stretching vertically, and I don't know why

Comment: Yes, the red one

Comment: do step 1 with it also

Comment: do step 2,3 ask if you don't understand they are the solution

Comment: I don't understand step 2

Comment: and the problem is in the red label

Comment: I know , but this is the reason , you see the label with content xoroshop delete it's bottom constraint , and hook it's bottom to the image below it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162283/discussion-between-mr-jo-and-sh-khan).

Comment: I found where is problem. Because of text is in Cyrillic, one letter takes space for 3-4 letters, because it's a code, not a letter actually. And how to solve this?